# Moved servers, and now getting a Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I just switched from a dedicated server to a virtual server.  I have a development site that I have that this function worked just fine, but now does not work:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname_connAdmin, $username_connAdmin, $password_connAdmin, $database_connAdmin);
 $adCats = mysqli_query($link, "call adTypes()");
```

And this is what I get in the browser now:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

I am totally lost as to how to get this working.  I have a page that does php_info at http://www.randykrohn.com/test.php

Here is the page in question (and every other page on the site, because the error is occurring on an included page).

Comment: mysqli is not present according to php-info page linked. mysql != mysqli.

Answer (score 3):

*mysqli* extension is not loaded. Apparently, you have a compiled version of PHP (as opposed to a pre-compiled binary). You will need to recompile with mysqli support:

```
./configure --with-mysqli=/path/to/mysql_config ...
```

See [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this through Cpanel?

Comment: If it's compiled, most likely: no. If you have a PHP installation that supports DSO extensions, you might, but you will have to refer to cPanel's documentation for that (I don't know a thing about it myself).

Comment: I actually found the option,  I could recompile it right in CPanel.  Thank you for you help!

Comment: make sure to Accept an answer!